# Как верифицировать ALPINE LINUX 3.9?

Tags: linux, gpg, alpine-linux

Скачиваю Alpine Linux стандартную версию.

```
wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/releases/x86_64/alpine-standard-3.9.0-x86_64.iso
```

На [их сайте](https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/) висит GPG ключ.
GPG 0482 D840 22F5 2DF1 C4E7 CD43 293A CD09 07D9 495A

Но при проверки им

```
gpg --verify ncopa.asc alpine-standard-3.9.0-x86_64.iso.sha256
```

пишет что **gpg: verify signatures failed**: **Неожиданная ошибка.** 
Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему ncopa.asc — это сам ключ, а не подпись, его можно импортировать в свою связку:

```
gpg --import ncopa.asc
```

Дабы далее с его помощью проверять сами подписи, которые должны располагаться [здесь](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/releases/x86_64/alpine-standard-3.9.0-x86_64.iso.asc), но по ссылкам для всех дистрибутивов возвращается 404. Судя по всему разработчики забыли подписать/выложить подписи. По этому поводу стоит связаться непосредственно с ними.

Comment: ясно. спасибо Вам. Оказывается не я один такой. Связались с разработчиками, но от них пока что тишина. Наверное дистрибутив заброшен и не пользуется популярностью?? 
[ссылка](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/9952)

Comment: @Ivan , а посмотреть даты релизов и мержи в мастер (development) тут https://alpinelinux.org/ не судьба?

Comment: @TotalPusher да вроде бы не заброшен, (глянул сейчас). Может бы тогда просто забыли выложить.

Comment: @Ivan alpine используется просто в зашкаливающем количестве докер образов, так что жив, баги есть всегда, на тот баг уже назначен разраб, пофиксят рано или поздно.